# How to properly use SUMIF in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to achieve this in excel having two sheets where I want to get the sum of ID by matching it against sheet 2. But got stuck. I am confused whether I need both `vlookup` and `sumif`, or if only `sumif` will get me results.

Sheet 1

```
ID
12343
14563
23512
675432
```

Sheet 2

```
    ID      PAYMENT
    12343    60
    14563    80
    23512    45
    12343    30
    675432   25
    14563    70
```

Expected OUTPUT

```
ID         PAYMENT
12343       90
14563       150
23512       45
675432      25
```

I tried the following but I didn't get right result.

```
=SUMIF(E:E,sheet2!A2,sheet2!B:B)
```

Comment: no..it is in two different sheets...i want to do it with formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is one of these:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet2!A:A, $A2, Sheet2!B:B)      -- references the whole column
=SUMIF(Sheet2!A2:A7, $A2, Sheet2!B2:B7)  -- references only the used cells
```

(or similar based on your actual columns and rows - my tables start both in `A1`).

Explanation of the parameters:

1. The data you are using for the condition
2. The condition (`$A2`: column `A` is fixed, row `2` is different in each row)
3. The data to be summed

Sheet 2:

[image: Sheet 2]

Sheet 1 - whole column references:

[image]

Sheet 1 - references only the used cells:

[image]

Comment: ..Thanku for your reply but my issue is my data is on two different sheets and not on same sheets. can u please help me how to solve this query. As your results are only in consideration of sheet 2. :)

Comment: @garry so you have the IDs in Sheet 1, values in Sheet 3, and you want to have your result in Sheet 3?